# Apple rejected my App due to restore IAP

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have a Restore button. The problem is if they havent' done a restore, and they try to purchase an item, and they have already purchased that item, I need to tell them they already purchased it and not perform the purchase. So I need a way to know, without doing a restore, which items they've purchased. I tried doing a restore first, whenever the user tries to purchase, but apple rejected my app. They said a restore cannot occur before the Confirm In-App Purchase dialog is displayed.

Please help me to find the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is your best bet. But any form of storage will work just as long as you are responsible for obtaining the information. Seems like a design flaw, wouldn't you think? I understand they want to keep user data secure, but jeez.

Comment: If the user attempts to purchase a non-consumable product again, they won't be charged again. Instead, they'll be given a message saying that they've already paid and can get it for free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep those data in [NSUserDefaults](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore). And you don't need to show an Alert saying that the items are already purchased. If its a non-consumable product apple is showing the alert saying that they have already purchased that item!

**EDIT:**

1) You need to add 3 buttons to your view

- Buy Button
- Restore Button
- Demo Version

You need to give the user the restore option if you supports in-app purchases in your app. Otherwise Apple will reject your app.

2) If the user press the Buy Button, don't check whether the user has already purchased your app or not. Because Apple won't charge the users twice for the same non-consumable product. So just go through your buying code and if the the user has already purchased it Apple's StoreKit framework will call it's delegate method

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

with

> SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

transaction state. So you can present him the login screen.

3) If the user press the Restore Button just go through with your restore code

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

and like in the 2nd step it will call the delegate method with the same transaction state. So you can present the login page to the user.

4) If the user press the Demo version button, Present him the demo version.

5) If a user purchased your app, Deleted it and if he re-install it, treat him as a new user. Present him those 3 buttons and the user can restore the purchase and then you can present him the login page.

6) If you really need to keep on track whether the app is purchased on a exact device, then you can use the Keychain to store your data, because the Keychain items are not deleted even if the app is Uninstalled or removed. This Api will help a lot [link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore), have a look

or

You can refer to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW30) on Keychain data

Comment: This won't work reliably: The user might have bought the app on another device (or via iTunes); the user might have removed the app manually or wiped the device...

Comment: If the user uses the same apple id then apple will not charge the user again and you will get the delegate method called saying the in-app purchased. So you can unlock the hidden features of your app

Comment: Exactly. Which means that using `NSUserDefaults` wouldn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It can be helpful. The question says  "I need to tell them they already purchased it and not perform the purchase". So if when a user purchase an item he can store those data in "NSUserDefaults" and check whether the user has already purchased that item by just checking the "NSUserDefaults". But it doesn't work for two devices.

Comment: Apple would still reject his app for the stated reason, so no, it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: I have two apps in the app store which supports in-app purchases. I have a restore button separately and shows the product list separately. And if a user purchase an item I keep that data in my NSUserDefaults and when the user comes to the in-app purchase page I don't show him the products that he has already purchased. Simple as that!!

Comment: @Ushan87: +1 Thank u for your nice flow and explanation.Before Accepting i need to check with my app flow.

Comment: @Ushan87: If we already purchased the app we will get a popUp "you have already purchased.Tap ok to again download for free." and with two buttons cancel and ok.Can we find Where it will be triggered when user clicked on Cancel or Ok.

Comment: It will call the delegate method, "- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions" with "SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed" transaction state

Comment: @Ushan87: when i click on Ok then the state is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

Comment: yep when you press OK the state is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased and when you press cancel the state is SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29525/discussion-between-pm444-and-ushan87)

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple "a restore cannot occur before the Confirm In-App Purchase dialog is displayed." use the **- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
function** , check the code

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {  
     NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

// Call This Function
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog(@"%@",purchasedItemIDs);
    }
}
```

Comment: :Thank you for give me the reply.This is also nothing but calling Restore method before the confimation of inAppPurchase know
!

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge there is no other way to do this.

You should provide a Restore Button for Restoring the In-App purchases, Else Apple will reject your App.

You won't connect to In-App servers or restore a profuct without display the In-App purchase confirm alert.

Comment: :Yes you are right , I have already a restore button but before entering that screen i need to check weather the product is Purchased or not.

Comment: @pm444: that's not possible. When the user clicks on the Purchase again it'll give a response like : `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

Comment: I have two apps in the app store which supports in-app purchases. I have a restore button separately and shows the product list separately. And if a user purchase an item I keep that data in my NSUserDefaults and when the user comes to the in-app purchase page I don't show him the products that he has already purchased. Simple as that!!

Comment: @Ushan87: Actually my requiremnet is different.I need to know Weather the available product is already purchased or not at the firt time of launching the app.

Comment: @MidhunMP:Actually i have two buttons.When user click on btn1 I need to check weather he purchased that product or not.If he purchased the User can use the app otherwise it asks for payment after payment successfull user can able to register in to app.If btn2 is clicked demo of app wii be appears.This is my flow.Can you help me to get the right flow.